# Archive old content data in different database

Tags: 7, performance, backups

How can i make archive my old content and save in different db with my cron job.

I want to store in different DB because i want to increase my site performance.

In drupal 7 what's the best way to do it ?

Comment: Do you want to archive specific content or your entire database?

Comment: i want to archive specific content types. Because in some content type i have more than 50,000 nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

- Add your archive database to your settings.php below your default database.

  ```
  $databases['my_other_db']['default'] = array(
    // Your secondary database's credentials here.
    // You will be able to explicitly connect to this database from your modules.
  );
  ```
- In your cron script, load all nodes you want to archive. In this example I retrieve all nodes older than a month and no more than 50 at a time.

  ```
  $nodes_to_archive = array();

  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('node')
    ->condition('type', 'your_content_type')
    ->condition('created', REQUEST_TIME - (86400 * 30), '<')
    ->range(0, 50);
  $result = $query->execute();

  while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $nodes_to_archive[] = $record;
  }
  ```
- In the same script, switch from database and add the nodes to the archive (make sure the second database has the same structure as the existing one)

  ```
  db_set_active('my_other_db');

  foreach ($nodes_to_archive as $node) {
    db_insert('node')
      ->fields($node)
      ->execute();
  }
  ```
- Still in the same script, switch back to the default database and remove the archived nodes.

  ```
  db_set_active();

  $nids = array();
  foreach ($nodes_to_archive as $node) {
    $nids[] = $node->nid;
  }

  node_delete_multiple($nids);
  ```

I haven't tested any of this so you might need to improve it here and there. If anything's unclear, please ask.

Here is a list of helpfull resources:

- [How to connect to multiple databases within Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/18429)
- [Function db_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7)
- [Function db_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_insert/7)
- [Function node_delete_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Patrick Scheffer. One more doubt how can i join my default db and my_other_db to create some statistic reports ?

Comment: What data do you want to display in those reports?

Comment: Like all nids count with different criteria, in this count I have to show archive nodes also...

Comment: It's not possible to query two databases at the same time. There are 2 things you can do: You could query them seperately, merge the results and cache it to prevent execution at every request or create a custom table in your active database where you update the stats every archive run.