# Save Nodes with Field collection in a different database

Tags: 7, database, performance

I am trying to node_save($node) in different database. Second DB is clone of first DB.

its the part of [Archive old content data in different database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188764/archive-old-content-data-in-different-database)

I am trying with following code

```
  $node = node_load($nid);
  db_set_active('archive_db');
  field_info_cache_clear();
  node_save($node);
  db_set_active();
```

But its not working. Is anything i am doing wrong ?

i want to use node_save because in my node, number of fields, field_collection, entity_refrences are available.

Comment: Have you try to read the data from that new DB, does it work?

Comment: hi @Namari :  Yes, i am able to read the  data from my newDB.

Comment: One thing i also noticed, i am able to update node. Means same node if exist in both db and i have updated in default db then its  updating in 'archive_db' using above code. But its not working if node is not present in ''archive_db'.

Comment: Try this: unset($node->nid);
$node->is_new = true;  have you tried entity wrapper?

Comment: Thanks @Namari, Now its saving the node , and adding field_collections and entity_reference also but data is not saving :( for field_collections.

Comment: Do you have the exact same content type from one DB to another? In your node_load, do you have all the data?

Comment: Yes @Namari content types are same. ArchiveDB is the clone of defaltDB. At the time of reading I have all data including field collection

Comment: Have you tried the way they do it in the link you posted? You could use entity as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it was working for me:

```
$nid = '2841';
$item_ids = array();
$node = entity_load('node', array($nid), array(), true);
foreach ($node[$nid]->field_COLLECTION_NAME[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $value) {
    $item_ids[] = $value['value'];
}

//load the field collections
$fc_item = entity_load('field_collection_item', $item_ids);

//change db
db_set_active('my_custom_db');

$clone = new stdClass();
$clone = clone $node[$nid];
unset($clone->nid); 
unset($clone->vid); 
$clone->is_new = true;

//save node so we can use the new nid to link the field collection
entity_save('node', $clone);
//gives you the nid of the new node created
dsm($clone->nid);

//save the field collections
foreach ($fc_item as $key => $value) {
    //unset values
    $value->is_new = true;
    $value->revision_id = NULL; 
    $value->item_id = NULL;
    //link it to a node
    $value->setHostEntity('node', $clone);
    $value->save();
    dsm($value);
}


dsm(entity_load('node', array($clone->nid), array(), true));
//go back to the default DB
db_set_active();
```

Comment: Are you used field_collections with unlimited value in you entity ? My problem with Field_collections and Paragraph entity values are not saving;

Comment: Is your field collection in the node_load?

Comment: I've edited, have a look.

Comment: same code i already tried , but no luck :(

Its not saving the value

Comment: I've edited, this should work. I had a weird behaviors giving me empty field collection before the one with the data, it disappears once the node is saved though.